# Android: action_send put extra_stream from res/drawable folder causes crash

Tags: android, drawable, send

I am creating a game, and trying to allow the user to share their win via text/facebook/etc.  I am using the code below to grab an image from my res/drawable folder.  I am pretty sure I am doing it right, but my app keeps crashing after I choose the send method (ex. facebook).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Intent ShareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
ShareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
Uri winnerPic = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.poop.pals/" + R.drawable.winnerpic);
ShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, winnerPic);
startActivity(ShareIntent);
```

Comment: other apps have no access to your resources, you need to copy that file to some place that is accessible to other apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android's resources are only accessible to your app via the resource apis, there is no regular file on the filesystem you can open in other ways.

What you can do is to copy the file from the `InputStream` you can get to a regular file in a place that is accessible to other apps.

```
// copy R.drawable.winnerpic to /sdcard/winnerpic.png
File file = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "winnerpic.png");
FileOutputStream output = null;
InputStream input = null;
try {
    output = new FileOutputStream(file);
    input = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.winnerpic);

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int copied;
    while ((copied = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, copied);
    }

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("OMG", "can't copy", e);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("OMG", "can't copy", e);
} finally {
    if (input != null) {
        try {
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
    if (output != null) {
        try {
            output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The IDE might throw a warning if you don't reference the drawable with R. **raw** .mydrawable